# How to connect FTPS using jenkins and copy files there

Tags: ftp, jenkins, ftps

I am trying to access FTPS site using jenkins "Publish over ftp" plugin.

With winscp, I am able to connect but with with jenkins I wasn't able to.

[image]

I tried with option "Use Implicit TLS" checked but no use.
Even I tried with Explicit TLS also in jenkins configuration page but no use.

I am getting this error.

> jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to connect
> and initialize FTP connection. Message: [java.net.SocketException:
> Connection reset]

Please suggest.